# Bulk assign new categories to posts in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

**Input data:**

42,000 posts

400 terms in catalogs

200 terms in tags

80,000 terms in a custom taxonomy created from the intersection Catalog Term Name + Tag Term Name

Can you tell me how to link posts en masse to custom catalog terms?

**For example:**

We are sorting entries by catalog term News and tag term Barcelona, after sorting we get 120 posts.

```
?category_name=news&tag=barcelona
```

I need to link these 120 posts to the custom catalog term Barcelona News, which was created from the intersection of Сatalog term (News) + Tag term (Barcelona).

Doing it manually is not an option, I would like to do it in real time or by cron.

This function works fine on a small site, but my knowledge is not enough to work with such a large amount of data

```
// Registering a new taxonomy
function custom_taxonomy()
{
  $labels = array(
    'name'              => __('Cataloge'),
    'singular_name'     => __('map'),
  );

  $args = array(
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'map'),
  );

  register_taxonomy('map', array('post'), $args);
}

add_action('init', 'custom_taxonomy');


// Cartesian product, form an array from the intersection of Category + Tag
function array_cartesian()
{
  $_ = func_get_args();
  if (count($_) == 0)
    return array(array());
  $a = array_shift($_);
  $c = call_user_func_array(__FUNCTION__, $_);
  $r = array();
  foreach ($a as $v)
    foreach ($c as $p)
      $r[] = array_merge(array($v), $p);
  return $r;
}

// Generation of new Category elements based on Category and Tags arrays
function add_tax()
{
  // Getting all elements of the category
  $categories = get_categories([
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'exclude' => 1
  ]);
  $ar_cat = array();
  foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $ar_cat[] = $category->slug;
  }

  // Get all the elements of the tags
  $tags = get_tags();
  $ar_tag = array();
  foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $ar_tag[] = $tag->slug;
  }

  $cross = array_cartesian($ar_cat, $ar_tag);

  foreach ($cross as $cr) {
    print_r($cr[0].' - '.$cr[1].'<br>');

    // Generating new Catalog elements
    $name = get_term_by('slug', $cr[0], 'category')->name . ' ' . get_term_by('slug', $cr[1], 'post_tag')->name;
    $taxonomy = 'map';

    // first we need to check that the term does not exist
    if (!term_exists($name, $taxonomy)) {

      // ok, let's try to add a category
      $cat = wp_insert_term($name, $taxonomy);
      if (!is_wp_error($cat)) {
        echo '<script>console.log("Category added, its ID=' . $cat['term_id'] . '")</script>';
      } else {
        echo $cat->get_error_message();
      }
    }

// we assign to the terms of the new taxonomy the records that have the category and tag that are the basis of the term of the new taxonomy
    $ida = get_term_by('slug', $cr[0], 'category')->term_id;
    $idb = get_term_by('slug', $cr[1], 'post_tag')->term_id;
    
    $post_idc = get_objects_in_term( $ida, 'category' );
    $post_idt = get_objects_in_term( $idb, 'post_tag' );
    
    foreach ($post_idc as $idc) {
        foreach ($post_idt as $idt) {
            if (has_category( $cr[0], $idt ) && has_tag( $cr[1], $idt ) && has_category( $cr[0], $idc ) && has_tag( $cr[1], $idc ) && $cr[0].'-'.$cr[1] == get_term_by('slug', $cr[0].'-'.$cr[1], 'map')->slug) {
            wp_set_object_terms( $idc, $name, $taxonomy, true );
            wp_set_object_terms( $idt, $name, $taxonomy, true );
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
add_action('init', 'add_tax');
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far then? WP has all sorts of functions to select posts based on various criteria, and to update their taxonomy / category terms as well.

Comment: I added my function to the description, which creates a new category when Category and Tag intersect, and it also binds posts from those intersections to the new category. This function works fine on a small site, but my knowledge is not enough to work with such a large amount of data.

Comment: In what way is the amount of data making a difference here? Do you get any errors, timeouts, ...?

Comment: After starting the function, the site immediately crashes due to server memory overflow.

Comment: Well then you will probably have to find a way to do the whole thing in smaller batches.